# Calculate the average without including last score

Tags: c++, while-loop

How can I calculate the average without including the last game. I don't want to include the last game as to end the loop the user needs to input -1. So, when the user types -1 this game is being included into the average, when it shouldn't be as this to end the game, not actual points. Is there a way around this?

```
while (points != -1) 
{ 
total = total + points;
game++;  
cout << "Enter the points for game " << game << ": ";   
cin >> points; 
average = total / game;
}    

cout << "\nThe total points are " << total << endl;
cout << "\n The average points are " << average << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What comes before this code snippet is key to writing the loop correctly. Can we get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just test your points before you divide the total and decrement if it's -1 this way:

```C++
while (points != -1) 
{ 
total = total + points;
game++;  
cout << "Enter the points for game " << game << ": ";   
cin >> points; 
if(points==-1){
game--;}
average = total / game;
}    

cout << "\nThe total points are " << total << endl;
cout << "\n The average points are " << average << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: rather than always incrementing and optionally decrementing, explore optionally incrementing and never decrementing.

Comment: yes possible. You mean to increment `game` only when `points` is different from `-1` right?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you want, partly based on description and the missing code. I'm assuming that -1 means "stop the loop"

Here is what I think you're looking for:

```
game = 0;
total = 0;

while (1) {
    ++game;
    cout << "Enter the points for game " << game << ": ";
    cin >> points;

    if (points == -1)
        break;

    total = total + points;
}

game -= 1;

if (game > 0)
    average = total / game;
else
    average = 0;

cout << "\nThe total points are " << total << endl;
cout << "\n The average points are " << average << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't need `game -= 1;` if  you set `game = 0;` instead of `game = 1;` earlier.

Comment: @user4581301 I considered that [and would change it] if `cout << "Enter the points for game " << (game + 1) << ": ";` is valid and intuitive enough? What do you think?

Comment: I see your point there. The repeated +1s would cost more than the -1 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (points != -1) // <--3
{ 
total = total + points;
game++;  
cout << "Enter the points for game " << game << ": "; // <--1 
cin >> points; 
average = total / game; // <--2
}
```

I marked the order of operations. The problem is that you're adding points to be averaged after checking for '-1'.

```
while (temp != -1)
{
    total = total + points;
    cout << "Enter the points for game " << game << ": ";
    cin >> temp;
    if(temp != -1)
    {
        game++;
        points = temp;
        average = total / game;
    }
}
```

I added a variable to temporarily hold the input value to be checked before modifying the primary variables to be averaged.

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what the point of `total = total + points;` is now that `points` is never assigned a value.

Comment: @user4581301 points is assigned a value in the if statement. If it's -1, the while loop ends and -1 does not get added to total. Otherwise it gets added in the next iteration.

Comment: Think about what you are doing. Why would you `total = total + points;` before reading the `point`? Is this not completely pointless? Why not move it to after the value's been read? You can chuck `temp` entirely.

Comment: @user4581301 I attempted to add as little as possible. This logic works, and I wanted to keep the while loop intact. This is neither the most efficient nor the most elegant, it's just one possible solution in the structure OP used. Points is modified in each event that the input number is not -1, and when it is and the while loop restarts that number is then added to total.